# Show that the equation of a straight line meeting the circle$x^2+y^2=a^2$in two points at equal distances$'d'$from a point$(x_1,y_1)$

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

Show that the equation of a straight line meeting the circle$x^2+y^2=a^2$in two points at equal distances$'d'$from a point$(x_1,y_1)$on its circumference is $xx_1+yy_1–a^2+d^2/2=0$. I tried to solve this problem by taking the centre origin and their making the line as chord of contact from the point given and making it another circle but could not solve it.

Comment: You should really try to come up with a better title than a fragment of the first sentence of your question.

Answer (score 2):

If $(h,k),(p,q)$ the two intersections $h^2+k^2=p^2+q^2=a^2$

$$d^2=(h-x_1)^2+(k-y_1)^2=h^2+k^2+x_1^2+y_1^2-2(hx_1+ky_1)$$

$$\iff2(hx_1+ky_1)+d^2-2a^2=0$$

Similarly, $$2(px_1+qy_1)+d^2-2a^2=0$$

So, the locus of the  two intersections will be $$2(xx_1+yy_1)+d^2-2a^2=0$$

Comment: Why did you do $h^2+k^2=p^2+q^2$??

Comment: @priyanka, Both $(h,k);(p,q)$ lie on the same given circle

Comment: Yes!! I realised it now thank you.